# pdf permission in SharePoint document library

Tags: pdf

I require assistance with regard to not allowing users to edit PDF documents that are saved in the SPO document library. Below are my queries:

1. Can users directly edit PDFs saved in the SharePoint library?
2. Will providing read or edit access affect the ability of users to edit PDFs in the SharePoint library?

I appreciate your help.

Best regards.